# what is the first ever object created in servlet's life cycle...?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

As I am new to Servlets i want to know what is difference between `ServletContext` and `ServletConfig` objects.

I want to know that in `servlets` lifecycle which object was firstly created on container startup.

Comment: ServletContext represents the whole webapp. ServletConfig represents the configuration of one servlet in this webapp. The javadoc explains that. Have you read it? Whether the container creates one before the other is meaningless. You shouldn't care about that. Why do you care?

Comment: Just wanted to understand the flow, as servletConfig scope is within the servlet and servletContext's scope is at application level which will be created when our application deployement time, but servlet will be configured thru init() method only which is accepting servletconfig as parameter so got confused when which object is being created and thank u for your answer

Comment: I don't understand why you think that it would be possible to configure a servlet without having a servlet context.

Comment: Sir, exactly where i got stuck while container startup can i say that firstly Servletconfig  object is being created for initializing the servlet or servletContext object is being created because am not able to find an accurate answer to this@BalusC